# ItemListener Checkboxes not working as intended

Tags: java, class, user-interface, jframe, listener

I'm currently having a problem with my newest project.
I'm a beginner, so please keep that in mind :D

What I want my project to do is to **change the font** of some text if a checkbox is selected, and make it return back to normal if it is deselected.

I already managed to implement that.

However, there are multiple rows of checkboxes. If 2 are selected and I deselect one of them, the text changes back to normal. I don't want the text to become normal as long as a checkbox in the column is still selected.

How can I do that? =(

Hopefully one of you can help me!

```
import java.awt.Color;

public class WindowBuilderTest extends JFrame
{

private JPanel  contentPane;

//Launch the application.
public static void main(final String[] args)
{
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                final WindowBuilderTest frame = new WindowBuilderTest();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
            catch (final Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

// Creating Frame
public WindowBuilderTest()
{
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 1280, 720);
    this.contentPane = new JPanel();
    this.contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(this.contentPane);
    this.contentPane.setLayout(null);

    // Create Font
    final Font headfont = new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 15);
    final Font headfontRed = new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 15);

    // Role Headlines
    final JTextArea txtTop = new JTextArea();
    txtTop.setEditable(false);
    txtTop.setText("TOP");
    txtTop.setBounds(180, 95, 32, 23);
    this.contentPane.add(txtTop);

    final JTextArea txtMid = new JTextArea();
    txtMid.setEditable(false);
    txtMid.setText("MID");
    txtMid.setBounds(252, 95, 32, 23);
    this.contentPane.add(txtMid);

    final JTextArea txtJng = new JTextArea();
    txtJng.setEditable(false);
    txtJng.setText("JNG");
    txtJng.setBounds(320, 95, 32, 23);
    this.contentPane.add(txtJng);

    final JTextArea txtAdc = new JTextArea();
    txtAdc.setEditable(false);
    txtAdc.setText("ADC");
    txtAdc.setBounds(389, 95, 32, 23);
    this.contentPane.add(txtAdc);

    final JTextArea txtSup = new JTextArea();
    txtSup.setEditable(false);
    txtSup.setText("SUP");
    txtSup.setBounds(453, 95, 32, 23);
    this.contentPane.add(txtSup);

    // Checkbox 1st row
    addCheckBox(183, 143, 23, 23, txtTop);
    addCheckBox(255, 143, 23, 23, txtMid);
    addCheckBox(322, 143, 23, 23, txtJng);
    addCheckBox(393, 143, 23, 23, txtAdc);
    addCheckBox(457, 143, 23, 23, txtSup);

    // Checkbox 2nd row
    addCheckBox(183, 200, 23, 23, txtTop);
    addCheckBox(255, 200, 23, 23, txtMid);
    addCheckBox(322, 200, 23, 23, txtJng);
    addCheckBox(393, 200, 23, 23, txtAdc);
    addCheckBox(457, 200, 23, 23, txtSup);

    // Checkbox 3nd row
    addCheckBox(183, 257, 23, 23, txtTop);
    addCheckBox(255, 257, 23, 23, txtMid);
    addCheckBox(322, 257, 23, 23, txtJng);
    addCheckBox(393, 257, 23, 23, txtAdc);
    addCheckBox(457, 257, 23, 23, txtSup);
}


private void addCheckBox(final int x, final int y, final int width, final int height, final JTextArea txtTop)
{
    final JCheckBox checkBox = new JCheckBox();
    checkBox.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
    checkBox.addItemListener(new FontChanger(txtTop));
    this.contentPane.add(checkBox);
}

class FontChanger implements ItemListener
{
    private JTextArea textArea;

    public FontChanger(final JTextArea textArea)
    {
        this.textArea = textArea;
    }

    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(final ItemEvent e)
    {
        if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
        {
            final Font boldFont = this.textArea.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD);
            this.textArea.setForeground(Color.RED);
            this.textArea.setFont(boldFont);
        }
        else
        {
            final Font boldFont = this.textArea.getFont().deriveFont(Font.PLAIN);
            this.textArea.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            this.textArea.setFont(boldFont);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways of achieving what you want to try to do but I believe the issue is more conceptually. Each checkbox that you add to your panel has its**own** FontChanger. Each of those FontChangers are not aware of other FontChangers or check boxes for that matter. What you *could* do instead, is to have a single FontChanger added to all checkboxes and then have a way of letting your single FontChanger know the state of each checkbox in the itemStateChanged() method. This way, you can check to see if/how many/which checkbox is selected and act upon that.

**EDIT : Here is a full example** (Note I have extensively modified your code and haven't tested it, this is just to give you a general idea. Also I got rid of most of the final keywords for code readability, besides if you have no specific reason to use a different thread to run your program, there is no need to run your WindowBuilderTest in a new Runnable(), see commented section).

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.*;

public class WindowBuilderTest extends JFrame
{

private JPanel  contentPane;
private FontChanger fChanger; //<--NEW
private JTextArea txtTop; //<--NEW
private List<CheckBox> checkBoxes; //<--NEW

//Launch the application.
public static void main(final String[] args)
{
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                WindowBuilderTest frame = new WindowBuilderTest();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
            catch (final Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    //just use this and comment out the whole Eventqueue block.
    /*
    WindowBuilderTest frame = new WindowBuilderTest();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    */
}

// Creating Frame
public WindowBuilderTest()
{
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 1280, 720);
    this.contentPane = new JPanel();
    this.contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(this.contentPane);
    this.contentPane.setLayout(null);

    // Create Font
    Font headfont = new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 15);
    Font headfontRed = new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 15);

    // Role Headlines
    txtTop = new JTextArea(); //<--NEW
    fChanger = new FontChanger(txtTop); //<--NEW
    checkBoxes = new ArrayList<CheckBox>(); //<-- NEW you will need to update your imports.

    txtTop.setEditable(false);
    txtTop.setText("TOP");
    txtTop.setBounds(180, 95, 32, 23);
    this.contentPane.add(txtTop);

    final JTextArea txtMid = new JTextArea();
    txtMid.setEditable(false);
    txtMid.setText("MID");
    txtMid.setBounds(252, 95, 32, 23);
    this.contentPane.add(txtMid);

    final JTextArea txtJng = new JTextArea();
    txtJng.setEditable(false);
    txtJng.setText("JNG");
    txtJng.setBounds(320, 95, 32, 23);
    this.contentPane.add(txtJng);

    final JTextArea txtAdc = new JTextArea();
    txtAdc.setEditable(false);
    txtAdc.setText("ADC");
    txtAdc.setBounds(389, 95, 32, 23);
    this.contentPane.add(txtAdc);

    final JTextArea txtSup = new JTextArea();
    txtSup.setEditable(false);
    txtSup.setText("SUP");
    txtSup.setBounds(453, 95, 32, 23);
    this.contentPane.add(txtSup);

    // Checkbox 1st row
    addCheckBox(183, 143, 23, 23, txtTop);
    addCheckBox(255, 143, 23, 23, txtMid);
    addCheckBox(322, 143, 23, 23, txtJng);
    addCheckBox(393, 143, 23, 23, txtAdc);
    addCheckBox(457, 143, 23, 23, txtSup);

    // Checkbox 2nd row
    addCheckBox(183, 200, 23, 23, txtTop);
    addCheckBox(255, 200, 23, 23, txtMid);
    addCheckBox(322, 200, 23, 23, txtJng);
    addCheckBox(393, 200, 23, 23, txtAdc);
    addCheckBox(457, 200, 23, 23, txtSup);

    // Checkbox 3nd row
    addCheckBox(183, 257, 23, 23, txtTop);
    addCheckBox(255, 257, 23, 23, txtMid);
    addCheckBox(322, 257, 23, 23, txtJng);
    addCheckBox(393, 257, 23, 23, txtAdc);
    addCheckBox(457, 257, 23, 23, txtSup);
}


private void addCheckBox(int x, int y, int width, int height)
{
    JCheckBox checkBox = new JCheckBox();
    checkBoxes.add(checkBox); // <-- NEW (add to checkboxes list)
    checkBox.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
    checkBox.addItemListener(fChanger); // <-- NEW (add the same listener to all)
    this.contentPane.add(checkBox);
}

class FontChanger implements ItemListener
{
    private JTextArea textArea;

    public FontChanger(JTextArea textArea)
    {
        this.textArea = textArea;
    }

    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)
    {
        if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
        {
            Font boldFont = this.textArea.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD);
            this.textArea.setForeground(Color.RED);
            this.textArea.setFont(boldFont);
        }
        else
        {
            //iterate through list of checkboxes to see if there's still one selected.
            boolean stillOneCheckBoxSelected = false;
            for(int i = 0; i < checkBoxes.size(); i++){
                if(checkBoxes.get(i).isSelected()){ // <- Verify the method here, not sure
                    stillOneCheckBoxSelected = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(!stillOneCheckBoxSelected){//if no check boxes are selected, reset
                Font boldFont = this.textArea.getFont().deriveFont(Font.PLAIN);
                this.textArea.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                this.textArea.setFont(boldFont);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Again, I haven't tested this, you may need to patch up things but I think you can carry on from here.
Here is a link to the JavaDoc for ArrayLists, you may want to consult that : [ArrayList JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

**Second EDIT:**
I re-read your question and you actually want this logic for a specific set of columns only, so you'll have to change the logic to add only the pertinent checkboxes to the list so that every time you do the check, only the pertinent checkboxes are checked.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) I understand the general concept, but I'm not sure how well I will be able to implement it on my own. Could you help me out by giving me a rough starting point?

Comment: Your WindowBuilderTest class should have a `private FontChanger fChanger;` variable. At the beginning of your constructor you then instantiate the variable like so : 
`..// Role Headlines 
final JTextArea txtTop = new JTextArea(); 
fChanger = new FontChanger(txtTop);..`
You then proceed to adding your checkboxes with the same addCheckBox() method, but instead your method will look like: 
`private void addCheckBox[..]
    final JCheckBox checkBox = new JCheckBox();
    checkBox.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
    checkBox.addItemListener(fChanger);..`
Then change your itemStateChanged().

Comment: IF this still isn't clear I can update my previous answer with more details.

Comment: No problem, consider checking my proposed answer as the selected answer for your problem if it is the case :).

Comment: Okey, I lost control over the code ^^ I don't really know what I'm doing right now. Can you give me some more detailed information? :/

Comment: Thank you so much for your help :) I'll try to implement that code over the next few days.